# ASP.NET VS2010 MsTest Debugger not stopping at breakpoints

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Just created a new ASP.NET website using VS2010 (did not change anything)

Clicked on *Test* menu item, used *Test Wizard* to generate test. Selected PageLoad of Default page to generate a test.

This has created a test `Page_LoadTest` ,all works fine as expected apart from debugger does not stops at breakpoint I put in `Page_LoadTest` test.

Test method generated is as follows

```
 <TestMethod(), _
 HostType("ASP.NET"), _
 AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("c:\documents and settings\z08763ddev\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3", "/"), _
 UrlToTest("http://localhost:1560/"), _
 DeploymentItem("WebApplication3.dll")> _
Public Sub Page_LoadTest()
    Dim target As _Default_Accessor = New _Default_Accessor() ' TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
    Dim sender As Object = Nothing ' TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
    Dim e As EventArgs = Nothing ' TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
    target.Page_Load(sender, e)
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently using host "ASP.NET" attribute causing breakpoints not to stop. If I change the host type break points works. However I am still trying to figure out how to make breakpoint work in "ASP.NET" host

Answer (score 2):

Instead of selecting **Run Selected Tests**, there's a drop down arrow for **Debug Selected Tests**.  If you just run your tests, you'll have the behavior you're seeing.  No breakpoints will be hit.

But if you specifically select **Debug Selected Tests** your breakpoints will be hit and execution will be paused for debugging.

Comment: @suhailkhan Then your breakpoints simply aren't getting reached or you don't have them set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting a breakpoint, try adding this line to your unit test:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

This will cause the JIT debugger to ask if you want to debug w3wp.exe, and it will let you choose a new instance of Visual Studio to do the debugging.